# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

### build.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
// Firebase performance
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
       debug {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

   buildTypes {
       release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
//            useProguard true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
       debug{
           minifyEnabled true
       }
   }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[8,9)'
    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.7.0.0'
    // Firebase performance
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf'
}
```

### command:

```
flutter build appbundle --release
```

### error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.

> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 33s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                            274.6s
[!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

In `gradle.properties` added:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
```